# application restarting when changing orientation even after locking in android

Tags: android

I want to prevent my application from restarting when orientation of device changes. I have lock the app orientation as per below code but it doesn't help for the same.

```
<activity android:name=".CheckMemory"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/customTheme"
              android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
```

and

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //Do nothing here
    }
```

Comment: Define "restarting". What behaviour are you seeing, for this Activity? Are there any clues in the logcat output as to what's happening?

Comment: I got the answer from the link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Quotes from above link

"Handling the Configuration Change Yourself

If your application doesn't need to update resources during a specific configuration change and you have a performance limitation that requires you to avoid the Activity restart, then you can declare that your Activity handles the configuration change itself, which prevents the system from restarting your Activity"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did below and works well.

```
<activity android:name=".CheckMemory"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/customTheme"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity> 

@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remember that screen orientation is defined per activity. So if you have other Activities than `CheckMemory`, they will still respond to a change in orientation. You need to define `android:screenOrientation` for all your Activities.

Secondly, you seem to be calling super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig), will this not just do what the system will normally do? 
Try to remove that line and really leave the method empty (really do nothing).

Comment: Leaving the method empty will cause the system to throw an exception. You can safely just remove the method entirely if you're not doing anything in it.

Comment: I just do the below and works, don't know how.
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}